# If the underlying metric is totally bounded, then so is its induced Hausdorff metric

Tags: solution-verification, metric-spaces, compactness, hausdorff-distance

Let $(E, d)$ be a metric space and $\mathcal C$ the set of all non-empty compact subsets of $E$. We define [a metric](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4501594/hausdorff-distance-on-the-metric-space-containing-compact-subsets) $d_H$ on $\mathcal C$ by
$$
d_H (A, B) := \max \left  \{  \max_{x \in B} d(x, A),  \max_{y \in A} d (y, B) \right \}\quad \forall A,B \in \mathcal C,
$$
with $d(x, A) := \inf_{y \in A} d(x, y)$. I'm trying to prove below property which I have seen from this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance#Properties).

> **Theorem:** If $E$ is [totally bounded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totally_bounded_space#In_metric_spaces), then so is $\mathcal C$.

Could you please have a check on my attempt?

---

**My attempt:** Fix $\varepsilon > 0$. Because $E$ is totally bounded, there are $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_m \in E$ such that
$$
E = \bigcup_{i=1}^m B(x_i, \varepsilon).
$$

Let $\mathcal D$ be the collections of all non-empty subsets of $X := \{x_1, \ldots, x_m \}$. Clearly, $\mathcal D$ is finite and $\mathcal D \subset \mathcal C$. We pick a map $\varphi:E  \to X$ such that $d(x, \varphi (x)) < \varepsilon$ for all $x \in E$.

Fix $A \in \mathcal C$ and let $C := \{ \varphi (a) \mid a \in A\} \in \mathcal D$. We pick a "reverse" map $\psi:C \to A$ such that $d(c, \psi (c)) < \varepsilon$ for all $c \in C$. We have

- $$\max_{a \in A} d(a, C)  = \max_{a \in A} \min_{c \in C} d(a,c) \le \max_{a \in A} d(a, \varphi (a)) < \varepsilon.$$
- $$\max_{c \in C} d(c, A) = \max_{c \in C} \min_{a \in A} d(c, a) \le \max_{c \in C} d(c, \psi (c)) < \varepsilon.$$

It follows that
$$
d_H (A, C) = \max \left \{ \max_{a \in A} d(a, C), \max_{c \in C} d(c, A)  \right \} < \varepsilon.
$$

This completes the proof.

---

**Remark:** In a previous thread, I proved that

> [Theorem:](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4503460/if-the-underlying-metric-is-complete-then-so-is-its-induced-hausdorff-metric) If $E$ is complete, then so is $\mathcal C$.

By [this characterization](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4350573/let-x-d-be-complete-and-totally-bounded-then-x-is-compact) of compactness in metric spaces, we obtain the following corollary.

> **Corollary:** If $E$ is compact, then so is $\mathcal C$.